# React - Change Color Of a specific div inside a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i am studying React and Material UI and
I am trying to change the background color of the clicked div, for the moment they changed all.

I would like to change the background color from white to lightblue when one of the div is clicked and back to white only when we click on the other div.
I am getting the datas from a JSON file.
I hope it make sense.

I will share my code.

```
 <Grid sx={{ display:'flex' }} > 
    { props.supplies.map((supply,id) => {
        return(
          <Grid onClick={changeBackground} lg={4} key={id} sx={{ marginRight:"0.8rem", backgroundColor:`${background}`, border:2, borderRadius:2, borderColor:'#ddedf4', padding:'5px 8px 25px 25px' }}>
            <RadioGroup
              name={supply.months}
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={value}
            >
            <FormControlLabel value={ supply.months } control={<Radio size="small"/>} label={ <Typography fontSize='14px'>{supply.months}</Typography> } />
            <Typography marginLeft='30px'>{ supply.boxes }</Typography>
            </RadioGroup>
          </Grid>
        )
    })}
</Grid>
```

This code will render 3 divs with a checkbox and some text with a white background color from white to lightblue

```
  const[background,setBackground] = useState('white')  

 const handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => 
  console.log(e.target.value) 
  const changeBackground = () => setBackground('lightblue')
```

When i click on a div they all change background color.

Can someone help me to understand the problem, i am still a beginner.

Have a good day

Comment: you have to think of how react knows what div it should change ... for e.g. onClick setting the div id / unique thing related to div onclick to a state variable and while re-render check if the id in state matches set the class or colour

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of button with onClick listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904216/change-color-of-button-with-onclick-listener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maintain a state of the `<div>` index. The `map()` function provides you with an index argument ([doc here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#syntax)). In your case, its `id`
In your Grid onClick function, change the state to its index, and style it conditionally.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(-1);
map((data, index) => (
  <Grid 
    onClick={() => setState(index)}
    style={{
      background: state === index ? 'lightblue' : 'white'
    }}
  >
))
```

Comment: Hi Batman!, thanks for helping me , your solution really helped me a lot. I still have a problem with the Radio Button, when i click on it and on the label everything works fine, the background color changes as i want and the radio button is checked, but when i click on another part of the div the bg changed the color but the radio is not checked. Do you know how to solve this problem? Thanks again. Have a good day!

Comment: Do you mean the radio button gets unchecked? Can you share your new updated code? Just add a heading "Edit" and paste new code under it

Answer (score 0):

in your code,

```
// in your code
// css
.change_background{
    background-color:'violet'
}
<Grid sx={{ display: 'flex' }} >
    {props.supplies.map((supply, id) => {
        return (<Grid onClick={e=>e.currentTarget.classList.add('change_background')} lg={4} key={id} sx={{ marginRight: "0.8rem", backgroundColor: `${background}`, border: 2, borderRadius: 2, borderColor: '#ddedf4', padding: '5px 8px 25px 25px' }}>
<RadioGroup name={supply.months} onChange={handleChange} value={value}>
<FormControlLabel value={supply.months} control={<Radio size="small" />} label={<Typography fontSize='14px'>{supply.months}</Typography>} />
<Typography marginLeft='30px'>{supply.boxes}</Typography>
</RadioGroup>
</Grid>
)
})}
</Grid>
```

Hope it works