# how to add styling to a button in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

so I have a list of divs in a ul, I want to be able to click one of the divs and add styling when its clicked and when the next button is clicked the styling is deleted from the first one and then added to the second div.

I tried using an isActive state but this applies to all of them at once I only want it to work 1 by 1 like steps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of button with onClick listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904216/change-color-of-button-with-onclick-listener) a similar issue ...

Comment: Hello Ahmed, and welcome to Stackoverflow, I would recommend you to take a while to look at [StackOverflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , to take an idea how to write a very nice post so that people can help you. Also, I would recommend you to share a try with your own coding skills so we can focus on how we can solve the issue instead of giving you a very easy answer, because the goal of Stackoverflow is about "how to share issues and its specific solutions with all people", not to solve people's home work or to give a prepared solutions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is my first time asking a question i didn't know how to add my code that's why i couldnt add it @sohaiebazaiez

Comment: @ahmedlarbi I really understand that, that's why I wanted to help you by the recommendation I shared above ^^ welcome again to StackOverflow :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a list of divs and save state of each button.

For example:

```
const [buttons, setButtons] = React.useState([
    { title: "1", isActive: false },
    { title: "2", isActive: false },
    { title: "3", isActive: false }
]);
```

Then you can change state on click:

```
const handleClick = (title) => {
    setButtons(
      buttons.map((el) =>
        el.title === title
          ? { ...el, isActive: true }
          : { ...el, isActive: false }
      )
    );
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-fire-6r5b04?file=/src/App.js:271-469