# Changing buttons colours on click in react js,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 5 buttons created using map method.
When User clicks on the button, button should change colour to red. When User clicks another button - previous button need to change colour back to original colour, but newly pressed button should change colour to red etc. I got suck in finding the best algorithm for that. Ironically i think i solved this task a few month ago, but totally forgot. Your help will be much appreciated!

That's the code to create 5 buttons

```
 {priceranges.map((range, index) => (
        <Button
          key={index}
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: bgcolor[index].color,
            border: "1px solid pink",
            height: "30px",
            margin: "5px 5px 0 5px",
            fontSize: {
              xs: "0.6em",
              sm: "0.8em",
              md: "0.9em",
              lg: "0.9em",
              xl: "0.9em",
            },
          }}
          onClick={() => filterproducts(range, index)}
        >
          {range.displayas}
        </Button>
      ))}
```

This is priceranges array of objects:

```
  const priceranges = [
{ range: 0, displayas: "All" },
{ range: 1, displayas: "Under 50" },
{ range: 2, displayas: "$50-$79" },
{ range: 3, displayas: "$80-$199" },
{ range: 4, displayas: "$200+" },
```

];

That's the array i created to manage background colour for buttons

```
 const [bgcolor, setbgcolor] = useState(
new Array(priceranges.length).fill({ color: "white" }));
```

Thats the Onclick function:

```
const filterproducts = (range, index) => {
if (range.range === index) {
```

HERE I NEED TO PUT SOME LOGIC.

```
}}
```

Maybe my approach is totally wrong. But i hope my idea makes sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change color of button with onClick listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73904216/change-color-of-button-with-onclick-listener)

Comment: trying to figure it out. let me try applying it in my case

Comment: do you want the color to change on click or the red color to remain there until some new button is clicked?

Comment: Colour to remain till another button clicked. Also,  when u click on the same button again, colour should remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const priceranges = [
    { range: 0, displayas: "All" },
    { range: 1, displayas: "Under 50" },
    { range: 2, displayas: "$50-$79" },
    { range: 3, displayas: "$80-$199" },
    { range: 4, displayas: "$200+" },
];

export default function MyComponent(props){
    const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState(null)

    const filterproducts = (range, index) => {
        setActiveButton(index)
        if (range.range === index) {
          // Your logic here
        }
    }

    return <>
        {
            priceranges.map((range, index) => (
                <button
                    key={index}
                    sx={{
                        backgroundColor: activeButton === index ? 'red': 'white',
                        border: "1px solid pink",
                        height: "30px",
                        margin: "5px 5px 0 5px",
                        padding: '3px 10px',
                        fontSize: {
                        xs: "0.6em",
                        sm: "0.8em",
                        md: "0.9em",
                        lg: "0.9em",
                        xl: "0.9em",
                        },
                    }}
                    onClick={() => filterproducts(range, index)}
                >
                    {range.displayas}
                </button>
            ))
        }
    </>
}
```

Comment: that worked! thanks a lot!!  is activeButton some kinda special property for Buttons? Didnt know that

Comment: activeButton is not any special property. I used to store current button index and if the button's index and current index matches it'll show the effect.